# Storing permalinks in the database or building on-the-fly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, permalinks

I was going to ask this on Meta but I think it's a general enough question to warrant a place here instead.

I'm interested in knowing some of the ways you manage permalinks in your site, specifically permalinks that are built from data that can change over time.

StackOverflow is a good example of this whereby the URL to a question is partly made up from the question title. <strike>Without posting a dud question to test I'm unsure whether the link to the question changes if the title of the question changes. My guess is that it doesn't and if it does, a canonical is likely retained to the origional url.</strike>

*Changing the title on SO does not change the url*

Given that as the case is it common practice to store permalinks against posts in your database? and if so, how much of the permalink would you store?

I ask the latter because there's only one part of the URL that's variable in the context of SO, and that's the question title. So should we store only the sanitized title and build up the rest based on the static information we have from the post, or should we store the whole url including the controller name and Id (etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's relatively common to store the permalink in the database.  Space is cheap and string parsing functions can be expensive (making a question title HTTP friendly a few thousand times across thousands of questions will eat some processor) each time you want to display the link.

As for how much to store, personally, I would only store the HTTP friendly version of your question/post title in the DB (along with a primary key) for the following reasons.

1. Storing the entire or even part of the URL that concerns itself with Actions and Controllers will make it really, really hard to refactor/rename those things down the road.  You would either need to run mass DB updates or custom URL rewrites, etc.
2. Only storing the friendly version of the title allows you to use it in other places.  Let's take this URL to this question for example, it was probably generated by `@Html.ActionLink(Question.Title, "Index", new {controller = "Questions", Id = Question.Id, Slug = Question.Slug})`.  Keeping the slug as a separate parameter, you can use the questionId and questionSlug parameters in other controller/action calls and keep your URLs pretty.

Comment: From everything I can tell, SO doesn't store the title at all. The title in the URL is dynamic. The ONLY thing that matters is the unique ID of the question. Try it out, put http://http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887331/askjdkasjdf and you'll see it still takes you back here.

Comment: @AndrewFinnell - That just means that they are not using the title to actually retrieve the question, only the question ID.  But, when generating the links to put on a page, I would bet $$$ that they are storing the question title and the slug in a db.  Wordpress does the same thing (wp_post table)

Comment: I think you're right @Tommy. If you omit the title from the URL you're redirected to the titled version, which can differ from the actual title of the question.

Comment: Any reason for a downvote four years later?  Typically, one leaves a comment when doing such an action in order to help improve a response.

Answer (score 4):

What you usually want is some identifier uniquely identifying the data item you want to link to (in SO's case the question). How you build your URL is more a question of what you think you will be able to support for a long time and how to convey additional information to the reader.

If you look at SO URLs, you notice that they put the unique identifier at the beginning (the number after /questions/) which is enough to get to the question (try putting garbage in the rest of the URL, it will still redirect to your question). Therefore, the title at the end is just eyecandy for the user and not really used in resolving the question.